# Agile Web Development 4 (Chapter 12) Where does the line_items collection array come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been following along the Agile Web Development with Rails 4 book and everything makes sense on the part that I am on (Chapter 12). There is one particular line of code that confuses me. Here is the code reproduced below:

```
 33   def create
 34     @order = Order.new(order_params)
 35     @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)
 36     respond_to do |format|
 37       if @order.save
 38         Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
 39         session[:cart_id] = nil
 40
 41         format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Thank you for your order!' }
 42         format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
 43       else
 44         format.html { render :new }
 45         format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
 46       end
 47     end
 48   end
```

This is a create method for the file orders_controller.rb. I understand the logic of the code but there is one particular part that I can't figure out. ON ine 35, we define a method `add_line_items_from_cart` which is located in the order model. Here is is reproduced below:

```
  1 class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  2   has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  3   PAYMENT_TYPES = ["Check","Credit card","Purchase order"]
  4   validates :name, :address, :email, presence: true
  5   validates :pay_type, inclusion: PAYMENT_TYPES
  6
  7   def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
  8     cart.line_items.each do |item|
  9       item.cart_id = nil
 10       line_items << item
 11     end
 12   end
 13 end
```

I also understand what this code does and am able to follow along but what I don't get is where the line_items array came from. On line 10 of the above code, we shovel a line item into a line_items array for processing. Just where exactly is that coming from. I went back to the beginning of the section and in no where did I find an initialized array. Is this rails magic happening somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line_items array comes from the has_many :line_items declaration in the Order class. In the add_line_items_from_cart method, you are adding an item to the line_items collection on an instance of the Order class.

Comment: Hey liampronan, I tried running rails c to test this out but I get an undefined local variable line_items error when I create Order.new. However, I do get orders.line_items though as a legitimate collection object. I just want to clarify, so on any model that has a has_many relationship declaration, for example, product has_many orders, will I also have an accompanying defined orders array with the declaration?

Comment: Yes, the collection exists on an instance of the class. So, if you try to call line_items after creating Order.new, you are not calling it on that class instance, but if you call it on the instance, then it will be a legitimate collection object as you described. The line_items call works in the instance method definition of add_line_items_from_cart because ruby knows that you are referencing a particular instance of the Cart class, which has line_items defined on it.